# How to escape asterisk character in Redis PSUBSCRIBE call?

Tags: redis

I publish to a lot of channels with binary names. The names look like [binary_data]:[text data]. Sometimes I would like to subscribe to the channel as follows:

```
PSUBSCRIBE [binary data]:*
```

In this case if binary data contains an asterisk the matching can deliver unexpected results. Is there a way to escape the asterisk character in this circumstances?

Answer (score 2):

Use `\` with the asterisk (or question mark, or any other special char) you want to escape.

From the [psubscribe docs](https://redis.io/commands/psubscribe):

> Use \ to escape special characters if you want to match them verbatim.